# AttributeError: 'CRS' object has no attribute 'equals'

Tags: geopandas

I'm trying to make an interactive map with Geopandas using the default data-set.

```
countries.to_crs(epsg=3395)
countries.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='magma')
```

Now I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-92f1397b09bf> in <module>
      1 #Popultion mapping- Interactive
      2 countries.to_crs(epsg=3395)
----> 3 countries.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='magma')

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in explore(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1856     def explore(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1857         """Interactive map based on folium/leaflet.js"""
-> 1858         return _explore(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1859 
   1860     def sjoin(self, df, *args, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\explore.py in _explore(df, column, cmap, color, m, tiles, attr, tooltip, popup, highlight, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, width, height, categories, classification_kwds, control_scale, marker_type, marker_kwds, style_kwds, highlight_kwds, missing_kwds, tooltip_kwds, popup_kwds, legend_kwds, **kwargs)
    283         kwargs["crs"] = "Simple"
    284         tiles = None
--> 285     elif not gdf.crs.equals(4326):
    286         gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)
    287 

AttributeError: 'CRS' object has no attribute 'equals'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: world without issues for me geopandas 0.10.2 `countries = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outdated version of pyproj installed in your environment. You need at least pyproj 2.5.0. GeoPandas 0.10.x contains an installation *bug* that allows you to install older versions but this doesn't work. Update your  pyproj.

```
conda update pyproj
```

or

```
pip install -U pyproj
```

Also, note that the line `countries.to_crs(epsg=3395)` in your snippet above doesn't do anything. It does not work in place. You need to assign reprojected GeoDataFrame or use a keyword. But keep in mind that this has no effect on `explore` as it automatically retrojects geometries to Web Mercator.

```py
countries.to_crs(epsg=3395, inplace=True)
# or
countries = countries.to_crs(epsg=3395)
```

Comment: Thank you @martinfleis - this worked for me